# SSL protocol can protect a Web Service?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, wsdl, httpserver

If I make a web service and I publish the WSDL through the IHS (IBM HTTPServer) in the secure port 443 with a SSL Certificate, the communication sent between client WS and Web Service are secure?

Comment: yes if you are using only https it will be safe. So your endpoints addresses in WSDL must use the https:// prefixes.

Comment: Yes I use only https://mydomain/myWSService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it can**, but if you are making your own server *remove :80 port for http*, it is not necessary, but if you want to be it safe, you don´t need it, 
addresses must be like: https://something.com (.org .net .eu and so on) and it will use 443 port.